# DynamicJasper & Webstart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-web-start, dynamic-jasper

I've got a problem using DynamicJasper 5.0.2 with a Webstart application.
In eclipse -> No problem but in webstart I've got this error :

```
\\storage1\homes\sourin-v\Bureau\DJR_5724_1433511783056_171003.java:4: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
```

But I'm sure that JasperReport libraries (6.0.4) are in classpath because if I generate a "standard" jasper report in the webstart application it works flawlessly.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad. Missing JDT Compiler in classpath.
And it worked with a "standard" jasper report because it was a pre-compiled .jasper report.